# Transducer output wires in grounded enclosure - to twist or not to twist?

Tags: grounding

I have a transducer totally enclosed in a conductive brass casing, which is grounded. One of the transducer outputs is grounded, and the other fed from the enclosure by a coax connector.

Internally, is there any benefit twisting the transducer output wires prior to their terminating on the coax connector and earthed brass? Signal is small amplitude (mV) at 120kHz

I believe not, but would like a second opinion

Comment: Probably not...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Twisting the wires does not help against electric fields, but these are shielded by the brass case. Twisting does help against magnetic fields. But if there are only a few centimeters of transducer wires inside the case and some meters of coax cable from the case, twisting the wires would cause only a very small effect. I would suspect a benefit only if there is a strong magnetic field very close to the brass case.